# Subspaces of different dimension

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Suppose I have 2 finite dimensional vector spaces $W, V$, and $\text{dim } V > \text{dim} W$

Is it possible that some subset of $W$ is a basis for $V$?

Answer (score 0):

No. Assume, for contradiction, that such a subset exists. Then it would be linearly independent (by assumption) and would span *not just $V$ but also $W$.* So being a subset *of $W$* that is both linearly independent and a spanning set for $W$, the set would be a basis for $W$. But then $\dim W = \dim V$, a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the answer is *YES* it is possible, *assuming that the vector spaces can be over different fields*.

Consider the following two vector spaces:

- Let $W$ be the vector space $\Bbb C$ over the field $\Bbb C$, which is one-dimensional with basis $\{1\}$
- Let $V$ be the vector space $\Bbb C$ over the field $\Bbb R$, which is two-dimensional with basis $\{1,i\}$

We have $\dim W<\dim V$ and yet $\{1,i\}$ is a subset of $W$ which also acts as a basis for $V$.

The point being, a set might be linearly dependent in one vector space while being linearly independent in another depending on the field used.